# Как записывать в массив слова, разбитые strtok в Си?

Tags: c

Вот код, он разбивает массив чаров на строки:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
  char str[]={"Test func strtok"};
  char *istr;
  char sep[]={" \n"};
  istr=strtok(str,sep);
  while (istr!=NULL) {

    printf("%s\n", istr);
    istr=strtok(NULL,sep);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Но как я могу слова, которые он разбил, записать в массив по отдельности(каждое слово новый элемент) для дальнейшей работы с каждым словом?

Comment: `char s[много][много]; int i = 0; for(char * с = strtok(str,sep); c; с = strtok(NULL,sep)) strcpy(s[i++],c);` Как-то так...

Comment: А зачем мы создаем именно двумерный массив?

Comment: А чтоб было куда писать. Нет, если `str` у вас останется навечно - можно просто хранить указатели, но если вы ее перезапишете. например - то указатели будут указывать не пойми на что...